# How to use "microk8s kubectl" within a "skaffold.yaml" file?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, microk8s

I have a `skaffold.yaml`file like below:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  mk:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: learnertester/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: learnertester/ticketing-client
```

Now, I have installed `microk8s` on Ubuntu 22.04 and want to use it. I have also defined an alias `mk` for `microk8s kubectl`. But when I change the following line:

```
deploy:
  kubectl:
```

To:

```
deploy:
  mk:
```

I get the below error running `skaffold dev`:

```
parsing skaffold config: error parsing skaffold configuration file: unable to parse config: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 55: field mk not found in type v2alpha3.DeployConfig
```

How should I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [doc](https://microk8s.io/docs/getting-started) , use deploy as `microk8s kubectl` instead mk.
This might not be taking the alias mk or else you have not done a proper alias.

> add an alias (append to ~/.bash_aliases) like this:
> alias kubectl='microk8s kubectl'

Then use as below and have a try :

```
deploy:
  microk8s kubectl:
```

Refer to  this [skafold.yaml doc](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/) for more information on yaml and also  you need to use the correct dest path (#destination path in the container where the files should be synced to..)

You can also check out [Cloud Code for IntelliJ and VS Code](https://cloud.google.com/code) or the online [Cloud Shell Editor](https://ide.cloud.google.com/) which provides skaffold.yaml editing assistance, including highlighting errors in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  microk8s kubectl:
  manifests:
    - ./infra/k8s/*
```

......

"Property microk8s kubectl is not allowed.yaml-schema: skaffold.yaml"

I found this solution from here:
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/5283

Ubuntu 20.04 Server - microk8s Kubernetes - old laptop as a server

. Undo alias commented or delete the line:
# alias kubectl='microk8s kubectl'

```
nano ~/.bashrc
nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

. Install kubectl and export config

```
 sudo snap install kubectl --classic
 microk8s.kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config
 New config file created in my case....ls $HOME/.kube/
```

. scaffold.yaml infra/k8s the path for all .yaml files

```
  apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta1
  kind: Config
  manifests:
  rawYaml:
    - ./infra/k8s/*
```

.yaml for reference

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v3alpha1
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: ajochope/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.js"
            dest: .
manifests:
  rawYaml:
  - ./infra/k8s/*
deploy:
  kubectl: {}
```

Cheers!!